# What is PROC FREQ equivalent in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use the functionality that `PROC FREQ` provides in SAS. `PROC FREQ` helps in giving the statistics such as frequency, percent, cumulative frequency etc. of a variable or variables. The link attached explains the function in more detail. I am aware that I can use `PIVOT` in SQL Server to achieve somewhat the same objective. However, there are certain feature of `PROC FREQ` that I cannot find SQL equivalent. To be precise:

`table x/norow nocol nocum nopercent missing`

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_sect010.htm

This link helped me figure out that `table` is basically a cross tabulation technique, so how can I use `pivot` in SQL for this? Next, the `missing` treats missing values as non-missing. How can I do the same in SQL?

Any thoughts/advice/help much appreciated.

Comment: Isnt no percent one word? --> nopercent

Comment: The question assumes knowledge of what SAS' PROC FREQ, whatever that is, does. Please consider explaining what you want to achieve in human language.

Comment: Apologies, have briefly explained and attached a link for detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated a SAS PROQ FREQ Missing values example due to lack of more information.

Example:
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_sect016.htm

**Sas data set:**

```
   data one;
      input A Freq;
      datalines;
   1 2
   2 2
   . 2
   ;
```

**Sas Query:**

```
   proc freq data=one;
      tables A / missing;
      weight Freq;
      title 'MISSING Option';
   run;
```

**Sas result set**

[image]

**SQL Server Data Set --> Using two tables to number duplicate missing values**

```
DECLARE  @A TABLE (id INT,
      Freq INT);
      DECLARE  @B TABLE (id INT,
      Freq INT,
      rownum int);

      INSERT INTO @A
   VALUES( 1, 2),
   (2,2),
   (NULL, 2),
   (NULL, 2)
   ;
   insert into  @B(rownum,id,Freq)
   select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  id) , id, freq 
   from @A
```

**SQL Server Query: (compatible with SQL Server 2008)**

```
SELECT   B.id,
B.Freq as Frequency,
        (cast(B.Freq as DECIMAL(2,1)) / cast(sum(B2.freq) over() as DECIMAL(2,1)))  * 100 as Percentage ,
        sum(B2.Freq) as cumulative_frequency, 
        ( (cast(sum(B2.freq) as DECIMAL(2,1))) / cast(B.Freq as DECIMAL(2,1)) *2) / cast(sum(B2.freq) over() as DECIMAL(2,1))  * 100 as CumulativePercentage  
FROM @B B
inner join @B B2 on B.rownum >= B2.rownum
GROUP by B.rownum,B.id,B.Freq,B2.Freq
```

**SQL Server result set:**

```
id      Frequency   Percentage  cumulative_frequency    CumulativePercentage
NULL    2          25.000000    2                       25.000000000
NULL    2          25.000000    4                       50.000000000
1   2              25.000000    6                       75.000000000
2   2              25.000000    8                       100.000000000
```